# CSS display grid image issue

Tags: html, css, css-float

[image]

Hi,

I am so confused that why some of html page is displaying a grid as a screenshot.

It seems was entering to a new line.

Below is a css that I used.

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product,.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product{
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product.product-category:hover .container-inner h3,.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product.product-category:hover .container-inner h3{
    color:#000;
}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product.product-category,.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product.product-category{
    width:33.33%;
}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product.product-category a img,.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product.product-category a img{
    height:100%;
}
.product-category.product:nth-child(3n+1){
    clear:both !important;
}
.woocommerce ul.products li.product.product-category.first,.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product.product-category.first{
    clear:none;
}
.woocommerce ul.products.list li.product.product-category a img,.woocommerce-page ul.products.list li.product.product-category a img{
    width:32%! important;
    height:auto;
}
.woocommerce ul.products.owl-carousel li.product,.woocommerce-page ul.products.owl-carousel li.product{
    width:100% !important;
    margin:0;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem happens when an element is taller than others to its right, preventing next row elements to float to the fully left properly; in this case, the second item (which description is two lines) is causing the bug.

Possible solutions:

- Using a fixed size for each item, trimming the description
- Using a fixed size for description, which can take two lines (I'd go on this one).
- Changing the code so you don't rely on floats.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks, it seems like you said when i use substr() to fixed size for description. it display in the same lines.